# Fancybox in image container

Tags: css, fancybox-3

is possible to set up to load fancybox (I use fancybox 3) to image container? In documentation is it not anything similar, maybe some hack to do it?

I have simple html:

```
<div id="discount-popup">
  <h2>Discount</h2>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="email-input">Email</label>
    <input id="email-input" type="email" name="email" value="" required /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="send-discount" value="Send" />
</form>
```

And jquery to launch it after 5s after load page:

```
if ($('#discount-popup').length) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $.fancybox({
      autoSize: false,
      height: 'auto',
      minHeight: 385,
      width: 650,
      href: '/index/discount-popup',
      type: 'iframe'
    });
  }, 5000);
}
```

Content of popup would be in top of image. Image container could be something like that:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what are you asking. I have no idea what do you mean by "Image container", some background image behind iframe? Could you create a more complete mockup?

Comment: Image container is the black image which I posted in origin question. That image should be fancybox popup and content should be in top of image. I thing that position of content will not main problem as customizing fancybox popup. Is it more clear?

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? You do not know how to set background image using CSS? You do not know how to adjust spacing around iframe created by fancybox? Or what? Did you try anything?

Comment: Of course that I tried. Fancybox produced own wrappers, own styles and is not easy to change it (without change css in plugin).

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this, but it is still unclear what do you ask for:

```
.fancybox-slide--iframe .fancybox-content {
  width  : 780px;
  height : 460px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px 100px 200px 100px;
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZUaW.jpg) top left no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqzYWv?editors=1100